# Python - While loop should return string

Tags: python, string, while-loop

Again I'm somewhat stuck with a task. This time my while loop should return a string of comma separated numbers. I do get the comma separated numbers out when I print them but the whole thing should be inside a string, and that's where I fail.

The code I use:

```
a = 7
b = ""

while a <= 20:
    b += (str(a) + ", ")
    a = a + 3

ANSWER = b          # Same result with str(b)
```

This produce: `7, 10, 13, 16, 19,` and not `"7, 10, 13, 16, 19,"`
I don't think I should hard code it in... Any pointers on this?

Regards

Comment: That *is* a string, `print` won't show the quotes.

Comment: Note - you can do this using: `print(*range(7, 20, 3), sep=', ')` if you only really want to print it - but I imagine you're supposed to be using `range` if possible here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the surrounding quotes, try `repr()`:

```
b = "7, 10, 13, 16, 19,"
print(repr(b))
```

Output (single quotes only, this relies on `str.repr()`, you can change it):

```
'7, 10, 13, 16, 19,'
```

Or explicitly wrap them up or change `repr()`'s output to use double quotes:

```
print('"{}"'.format(b))
print('"{}"'.format(repr(b)[1:-1]))
```

Output:

```
"7, 10, 13, 16, 19,"
```

[`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) gives *a string containing a printable representation of an object*, and for most types, the result of `repr()` would be suitable for `eval()`, or to be put in your source code.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a String. You can test this by printing the value of type:

```
>>> print(type(b))  
<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 7
b = ""

while a <= 20:
    b += (str(a) + ", ")
    a = a + 3

ANSWER = f'"{b}"'
print(ANSWER)
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 letters_dict.py 
> "7, 10, 13, 16, 19, "
> ```

Comment: Note this answer requires Python 3.6 or newer (for the f-string).

Comment: @iBug Nice catch, I only began coding at Python 3.7 I forget that others may be using a previous version, will keep that in mind with future posts

Comment: That's fine. It's usually recommended to use newest version of softwares / code on newest platforms. But it's also important to know the difference between older versions. Good luck.